# How to get image from random byte array

Tags: go, webrtc, carplay

I'm working with decoder for Apple CarPlay which originally is using WebRTC and html video as display for it. I'm trying to replace html with Fyne image refresh.

Current source code looks like that

```
duration := time.Duration((float32(1) / float32(fps)) * float32(time.Second))

if videoTrack != nil {
    videoTrack.WriteSample(media.Sample{Data: data.Data, Duration: duration})
}
```

where videoTrack is:

```
videoTrack       *webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample
```

I've tried to move `data.Data` (since it's byte[]) into image converter, but I guess there's some more for that.

Im looking for some help in transporting these byte[] into image compression because that's the format Fyne is using, but without any success. Can anyone give me some hint in that?

Answer (score 1):

You can either load the `byte[]` to an image using standard go `image` package (blocking operation) or you can pass it to Fyne as a resource).
To do the latter try `canvas.NewImageFromResource(fyne.NewStaticResource(“streamName.png”, data))`.

After this setup you can set the `Image` or `Resource` on your image and call 'Refresh()` to update the display.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately it's not working. I get `2022/07/18 20:04:13   Cause: failed to decode image: image: unknown format
2022/07/18 20:04:13   At: /Users/michalporeda/go/pkg/mod/fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.2.3/internal/painter/image.go:56
` error. Problem is that this byte array doesn't have any headers related to any file format. That's why I need some way to transform incoming bytes into complete image :/

Comment: If you are doing more complex image processing you will have to take the first option and process it into an in-memory image that Fyne can render, using `canvas.NewImageFromImage`

Comment: Yes I know, and that's what my original question was about. How to make image from these bytes